# traffic information & displaying navigation ui

Tags: android, skmaps

Is there a possibility in Skobbler to show the traffic information?
Whether the road is "busy", there are some accidents on it or a traffic jam?
I would like to display such information in a TextView:

```
_information.Text= [insert function(?) about traffic information here]
```

Also I would like to know how to display a custom navigation ui. I saw in the demo project from Skobbler that there is a binding (Skobbler.SDKTools) and some functions like `CalculateFromSKTools` and some variables like `_skToolsNavigationInProgress`.
For what are these functions and variables used exactly? Are they used for displaying the navigation ui?

My plan is to add some TextViews with specific information about the distance, the destination time, the next turn to make, etc. But I am not adding an extra layout, I'm adding the Views, which I require and set it to `View.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone`. After the navigation is started (by pressing a button) the views will be visible (`View.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible`).

And what exactly is Skobbler.SDKTools and for what is it used?

**EDIT**:

Found the information about traffic in http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec032
But I have no functions in map settings to set the traffic mode. I searched in my assembly browser, but there is no function that contains this traffic information...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traffic is not enabled in the public version of the SDK - you'll need to receive a traffic enabled SDK version to access this API.

This is available only with an enterprise license - send an email at dev@skobbler.com for more details.

Comment: and what about the Skobbler.SDKTools?